# How to match a trait in a Rust macro?

Tags: rust, rust-macros, rust-decl-macros

My goal is to take as input trait type.

```
my_test_macro!(Trait1, Trait2<Test1, Test2=Test3>)
```

What I tried so far was writing parser like this.

```
$( $ty:ident < $( $N:ident $(: $b0:ident $(+$b:ident)* )? ),*  $($tname:ident=$ttype:ident),* > )+*
```

But it created local ambiguity.

```
error: local ambiguity: multiple parsing options: built-in NTs ident ('N') or ident ('tname').
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `ty` or `path` [metavariables](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/macros-by-example.html#metavariables), depending on what you want to do:

```
macro_rules! my_test_macro {
    ($t1:ty, $t2:path) => {};
}

fn main() {
    my_test_macro!(Trait1, Trait2<Test1, Test2 = Test3>);
}
```

See also:

- [Rust macro accepting type with generic parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41603424/155423)
- [Is it possible to write a Rust macro "has_trait!(<type>,<ident>|<expr>)"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37824384/155423)
- [How to match trait bounds in a macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51579647/155423)
- [What does "dyn" mean in a type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50650070/155423)

Comment: TIL you can use a `ty` variable where a trait is required: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0e16b9b4294bb480961284173247f7fb). I would have expected that to fail, like `impl dyn Trait for i32 {}` does. I wonder if this will change when bare trait syntax is dropped.

Comment: Yeah, I assume that it's the duality of `SomeTraitName` being either a trait *or* a type that allows that.